# Click on link using selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am very new to python programming and I need help in clicking a link on tripadvisor website. I need to extract full reviews. Current code take only partial reviews with More link. HTML code for More link is mentioned below. I clicked on Inspect element and copied the HTML code.

```
<span class="taLnk hvrIE6 tr395770395 moreLink ulBlueLinks" onclick="          var options = {
      flow: 'CORE_COMBINED',
      pid: 39415,
      onSuccess: function() { ta.util.cookie.setPIDCookie(2247); ta.call('ta.servlet.Reviews.expandReviews', {type: 'dummy'}, ta.id('review_395770395'), 'review_395770395', '1', 2247);; window.location.hash = 'review_395770395'; }
    };
    ta.call('ta.registration.RegOverlay.show', {type: 'dummy'}, ta.id('review_395770395'), options);
    return false;
  ">
More&nbsp; </span>
```

Thanks!

Comment: what did you mean by "full review"?

Comment: If you go to tripadvisor website..if a review by a customer is longer..its shows only half review with more link..if we click on more, the review is enlarged and full review can be seen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are basically two approach to clicking on the `More` as below :

- using `find_element_by_xpath` as below :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(.,'More')]").click()
  ```
- using `find_element_by_css_selector` as below :

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.moreLink").click()
  ```

**Note** : Before finding element and clicking make sure this element is not inside any `frame` or `iframe`. If is then you need to switch that `frame` or `iframe` before finding element and clicking as : `driver.switch_to_frame("frame name or id")`

Hope it works..:)

Comment: by x_path didn't work..it redirected me to a different url.. But by css_selector worked !!!! Thanks a ton!! :)

Comment: @RupalBansal it there are more link with text `More`.. selenium will considre the first link. So please make sure there is only one link with text `More`...any way you welcome.. Glad to help you.. Please accept the answer it it helped..http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work..:)

Comment: Hi, After hitting the more link..I basically want to extract text of whole review..But for some reason it is still giving me partial text..it clicks the more link on the webpage but while extracting text using beautiful soup, it still returns half review..Any help please?

Comment: @RupalBansal Please ask another question regarding this.. thanks

Comment: I tried that but this isn't allowing at the moment..anyways i will try in different forum..